# how should we build double map iteration inside each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

```
const items = this.state.items.map((result, key) => {
    const eachOne = result.map((item, key) => {
        console.log(item);
        return <td> { item } </td>;
    });
    console.log(result);
    return ( <tr> { eachOn } </tr>)
});
```

In that `const` above I need to display a table of an array of objects.

Array is kinda like this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

[{id: 1, name: "jad", country: "US"},
{id: 2, name: "tony", country: "UK"},
{id: 3, name: "alain", country: "US"}]
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Looks like you've got an array of objects. So if you try map over an object which is what `result` looks to be, you will get an error saying something like `.map() is not a function of result`.

Comment: if i do just one map the result is :
{id: 1, name: "jad", country: "US"}
{id: 2, name: "tony", country: "UK"}
{id: 3, name: "alain", country: "US"}
if I add the second map function the eror i get is 
Uncaught TypeError: result.map is not a function

Comment: So you should be able to return `<td>{result.name}</td>;`. Does that give the intended result?

Comment: if I integrate the second map function the error will be 
Uncaught TypeError: result.map is not a function

Comment: Yes, that's because you can't map over an object. You should be able to call each attribute in a td `<td>{result.name}</td>`

Comment: the point is that each array maybe be customized

Comment: You should try avoid looping through different objects. You can loop through an object using lodash map though - https://lodash.com/docs#map

Comment: so maybe the array will change

Comment: I have added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you say after the first map function you have a list of objects so you could do something like this inside your render function.(Not sure why you would need two maps). You can only map over an array.

```
render(){
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
       {
        this.state.items.map(result => {
        //each object on every iteration will be available in result
             return <td>{result.name}</td>
          })
       }
      </tr>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Note: that I am not sure how tables work regarding html. So that may need to be changed around some.

Answer (score 1):

To map over an object, you will need to use lodash map.

This should do the trick:

```
import { map } from 'lodash';

...

const items = this.state.items.map((result, key) => {
  const eachOne = map(result, (item, key) => {
      return <td>{item}</td>;
  });

  return (
      <tr>
        {eachOne} 
      </tr>
    )
});
```

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as correct if that helped. Thanks.